# Why Python not returning True after connecting ElasticSearch Server

Tags: python, function, elasticsearch

I have connected to Elastic Search(ES) with below code, but its not returning True. http://localhost:9200/ is giving proper output

```
name    "0jDPVkL"
cluster_name    "elasticsearch"
cluster_uuid    "9PfIve-HSP-v7kU__DbGmQ"
version 
number  "6.4.1"
build_flavor    "default"
build_type  "zip"
build_hash  "e36acdb"
build_date  "2018-09-13T22:18:07.696808Z"
build_snapshot  false
lucene_version  "7.4.0"
minimum_wire_compatibility_version  "5.6.0"
minimum_index_compatibility_version "5.0.0"
tagline "You Know, for Search"
```

The Python Code

```
import logging
def connect_elasticsearch():
    _es = None
    _es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
    if _es.ping():
        print('Yay Connect')
    else:
        print('Awww it could not connect!')
    return _es

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
```

I am trying to execute from the URL http://blog.adnansiddiqi.me/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-in-python/

Comment: Try pass kwarg `retry_on_timeout=True` to `Elasticsearch` init

Comment: tried retry_on_timeout=True but still issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code from the blog. Its working fine. I uploaded in the github also

https://github.com/mak705/Python_ELK/blob/master/recipie.ipynb

Courtesy : Adnan who wrote the blog http://blog.adnansiddiqi.me/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-in-python/

NB: In latest version of ES(6,x) we don't need to mention mapping tags that is starting from the mapping { . Its automatically detects and give the schema. In earlier version(5.x) we have to mention the schema